# Create a polygon from point cloud

Tags: java, polygon

I have a point(x,y) array and i want to use it to see if a point (x2,y2) is in the polygon created my the point cloud. How can I check it?

I found http://www.pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/hull_2d.php but I really don't know how to do he same with Java.

The only real goal is to create a method to check if a point is in or out of the polygon, I don't really need to create the polygon I think.

Comment: The link you posted seems to use an external library. You could try and do the same. Afaik there are pure Java physics libraries or JNI wrappers for physics engines like Bullet or ODE. Alternatively you could try and find some code that creates a convex/concave hull from a point cloud - shouldn't be too hard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use java.awt.Polygon. The constructor to create Polygon

```
public Polygon(int xpoints[], int ypoints[], int npoints)
```

Than use either of

```
public boolean contains(Point2D p)
public boolean contains(double x, double y)
```

passing the point x and y

Comment: So I can simply do `Polygon poly = new Polygon (points.getX(), points.getY(), points.getLength())` where points .getX returns all X values of my points, getY returns all Y values, and getLength the number of points?

Comment: @Supamiu correct, provided that your points are in order. If you just have a randomly ordered set of points you'd need to either calculate those that define the hull or the correct order for your input points.